# Need more info on SQL "WITH" clause

Tags: sql-server, with-clause

I was attempting to create a table `custom_table`

Product doesn't have price column and both pc and laptop doesn't have a type column.

So i need to know how to create a table using with clause during such a scenario?

Here is my query

```
with custom_table(model,type,price)
as
(select model,type from product
union
select model,price from pc
union 
select model,price from laptop)
select * from custom_table
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with the common table expression, but a problem with the union.
In order for the union statement to work you must have the same number of columns with the same data types.
My guess is that you need something like this:

```
with custom_table(model,type,price)
as
(select model,type, null as price from product
union
select model, null, price from pc
union 
select model, null, price from laptop)

select * from custom_table
```